# Are finite sets measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that countable sets are measurable. But is this set {1,2,3} measurable ? If so how can I think of this? I'm just struggling to get the concept behind it?

Comment: Sure, it's a closed set, and closed sets are Lebesgue measurable.  It's also a set of measure zero.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. How can we prove that the measure of this set is zero? and can we find a bijective function from this to the set of natural numbers to conclude that this is countable ?

Comment: Trujello, in his answer, shows you how to show that the Lebesgue measure of this set is zero.  There isn't a bijection from a finite set to a countably infinite set.  But it is already a subset of the natural numbers, so by definition it's countable.

Comment: The people who answered are using "countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite". i.e. there exists an injection into $\mathbb N$. This isn't uncommon. It strikes me as a little odd that you ask about set theory in parallel with measure theory?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I'm just trying to solve the following question and I'm trying to clear out basic facts about measure theory.   Q - f is a real valued function on real line. Prove that f is measurable if {x∈(n,n+1) | f(x)<a} is measurable for each integer n.

Answer (score 1):

A finite set is a countable set. So you instantly get that the result carries over to finite sets.

To really answer your questions anyways, the way you show this (assuming you're working in the reals with the standard Euclidean metric), you can just observe that for any $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
I_n = \left(n - \frac{\varepsilon}{2*3}, n + \frac{\varepsilon}{2*3}\right)  \qquad n = 1, 2, 3
$$
is a covering of $\{1,2,3\}$. Hence by countable subadditivity 
$$
m_*(\{1, 2, 3\}) \le \sum_{n = 1}^{3}\ell(I_n) = \epsilon
$$
and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we see that $m_*(\{1, 2, 3\}) = 0$. Since it has measure zero it is measurable. But you should know that finite sets are countable, and if you didn't, well now you know.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. But how can we prove that a finite set is countable? Can we find a bijective function from this set to the set of natural numbers?

Comment: It's a matter of definition, but I'll demonstrate why. Technically, a set $X$ is countable if there exists a function $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ is injective (one-to-one).

So, observe that $f: \{1, 2, \dots, n\} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(i) = i$ for $i =1 ,2 , \dots, n$ is injective for any finite set. Hence every finite set is countable.

Comment: Thanks. Got the answer

Comment: It does, if $X$ is infinite. Note that if (1) $X$ is infinite and (2) there's an injective function $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$, then it's also surjective; this is something proved in set theory. But it is because of this that you'll commonly see that "$X$ is countable if and only if there is a bijection $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$," when really it's safer to just say "$X$ is countable if there exists a one to one correspondence between $X$ and $\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is lacking quite a lot of of context, but assuming your are talking about Lebesgue algebra, then yes, since all finite sets are closed (union of finitely many closed sets are closed).